Winmerge parent folder navigation is broken
After certain version Winmerge is not accepting Backspace to navigate to parent folder.
I.e. if I compare folder D:\StreamOne\DirA\DirB with D:\StreamTwo\DirA\DirB I see files compared in DirB folders.
Old behavior was that hitting Backspace changes compared folders to DirA.
But this does not work anymore. Tree mode does not affect it.
Is it intentional change and is there a way to get back to old behavior?
Winmerge 2.16.40.

If you upgrade to 2.16.44?

@Ramhound: same problem

Well, downgrade in that case. This also sounds more like a bug report you need to fill than a question for this website - and whether it's intentional can be answered by you if you check recent changelogs.

Turns out that 'Include subfolders' option should be disabled to make it work:
https://github.com/WinMerge/winmerge/discussions/2568
